# WPF application fails to start due to strange dll error

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

UPDATE: The error described below happens also with an empty Windows Forms Application.

I have a simple WPF application in C# that works with Bing maps API.

The application does nothing except from showing a Bing map that was integrated through xaml code:

```
<m:Map CredentialsProvider="my api key that I removed here" 
       x:Name="myMap"
       Center="47.620574,-122.34942" ZoomLevel="12" Height="Auto" 
       "/>
```

I don't reference any particular third-party libraries except the `Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF`.

When I run the application it exits without giving any particular error message. By checking error logs with `eventvwr` I discovered that it has problems with some dll file stored in my `AppData\Local\Admworks` folder. The file is probably generated dynamically as it has a different name each time I restart the computer. The first time it was `jgmrysmv.dll`, the second `gfphosrs.dll` and so on. 
If I rename the `Admworks` folder the application works. However, when I restart the computer the problem returns. The `Admworks` folder is still there and the name of the dll file is different.

This is the error reported in event viewer:

```
Faulting application name: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe, version: 12.0.30723.0, time stamp: 0x53cf4fe5
Faulting module name: gfphosrs.dll, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5547e370
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x000024ce
Faulting process ID: 0xcbc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d08d4c5b92cf13
Faulting application path: C:\Users\alber_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\bin\Debug\WpfApplication2.vshost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\alber_000\AppData\Local\Admworks\gfphosrs.dll
Report ID: 9a3939cb-f93f-11e4-bf2f-74e5437876cd
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

This is the output I get in the debug window:

```
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\alber_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\bin\Debug\WpfApplication2.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\PresentationCore\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationCore.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\PresentationFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x1db0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1d78 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1d80 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: WpfApplication2.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\alber_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\bin\Debug\WpfApplication2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[7516] WpfApplication2.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073740771 (0xc000041d).
```

I tried putting the breakpoint at `InitializeComponent()` in

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

but the application stops before reaching that point.

Comment: A little code perhaps? More info on used third-party assemblies etc.? Have you run in debug mode with breakpoints?

Comment: What is Admworks? A third-party? A plug-in in Visual Studio? A malware (virus)?

Comment: I have no idea. I checked for malware and there seems to be none. There's no application or library with that name. The only folder on my disk with that name is the one in `AppData\Local`. Really strange.

Answer (score 1):

Not solved yet? Tried compiling to 32 bit instead of 64 yet? Frequent cause for dll problems.

Comment: It appears to have been malware. After cleaning the system with an anti-malware software the problems disappeared. But I cannot say it with 100% certainty. However, thanks for the suggestion. It might be useful to someone else having dll problems.